# Laravel 5 scout

Tags: php, laravel-5, algolia, laravel-scout

I'm still learning php and Laravel framework. I can't get this code working in my controller I instead put them in my view, but that's not what I want.
I want to all my logic in the controller but I can't figure it out how to do that.

```
// in my controller
public function index(Request $request) {
    $error = ['error' => 'No results found, please try with different keywords.'];
    $results = Actor::search($request->get('query'))->get();
    $results->count() ? $results : $error;
    return view('welcome', compact('results', 'request', 'error'));
}

// in my view
@if($request->has('query'))

@foreach($results as $result)
    {{$result->first_name}} &nbsp;
    {{$result->last_name}}
@endforeach
@else
    <p> Please Enter a Keyword</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
public function help(Request $request){

    $results = Actor::search($request->get('query'))->get();

    return view('welcome', compact('results', 'request'));
}
```

And in your view:

```
@if($request->has('query'))

    @if($results->count() > 1)

        @foreach($results as $result)
            {{$result->first_name}} &nbsp;
            {{$result->last_name}}
        @endforeach

    @else
        'No results found, please try with different keywords.'
    @endif

@else
    <p> Please Enter a Keyword</p> 
@endif
```